# REGEX if then |else

Tags: regex, if-statement

I am having a difficult time understanding the syntax for *if then|else*.

I'm looking at a large multiline chunk of text and attempting to retrieve a file number that could match a varying number of expressions. I want to start with the most restrictive match and if its not found move on to another possible match. I dont want to use a simple or `|` because I want to make sure that one match does not exist before evaluating the other possiblity.

For example I could have a file number in the format `ABC-12345` or I could have it in the format `ABC-1234567` (there are several other possibilities that make just matching the number of digits impractical as there  may be other masks all together, I think if I can understand how to properly structure the if statement for this simple example I can work into the rest)

I thought I might be able to accomplish this by using something like

```
?(?=[a-zA-Z]{3}-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}$)[a-zA-Z]{3}-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}$|[a-zA-Z]{3}-[A-Za-z0-9]{7}$)
```

I am trying to get at :If I get a match on the `ABC-12345` then return that, otherwise return anything that would match `ABC-1234567`

I am looking on different lines at the moment hence using the `$` , however I suspect I may need to change this to `\b` if I am searching on the same line

Comment: I don't understand. In what situation would it possibly match ABC-1234567 and not ABC-12345? The former contains the latter, so it would always return either ABC-12345 or nothing.

Comment: My first thought: Just use an [optional group?](https://regex101.com/r/5u5wZz/1) Not sure if I got you right.

Comment: there is no if-else in regex, because there is no "then". It matches or doesn't match. And the part(s) it matches can then be used for further processing, but that's not the job of the regex itself.

Comment: cyberbrain - thank you that may be where I am trying to get too much out of the regex. It appeared to me after doing a google search on if then else regex , that there was a construct for doing this, but I am probably misinterpreting the results.

Comment: Thanks bobble bubble, that would be the easy way except I only want to get the results of one group (I only want the results of the second group if the first group doesn't exist, regardless of where it might appear)

Comment: @cyberbrain [Conditionals](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) are an extra feature of major modern regex engines.

Comment: @JohnHollan For me it's not clear. Can you please edit your question and include some sample data that should match and not match and in which case what parts to match.

Comment: @bobblebubble oh thanks, learned something new now, but still: the _then_ and the _else_ part are used for the further match and not as a result, if I understood it correct.

Comment: @JohnHollan You want to capture in [two different *capturing groups* like this?](https://regex101.com/r/H8BM74/1)

Comment: @cyberbrain Yes, like that. However the syntax and functionality differs a bit among the regex engines but the basic idea like `(optional match grp 1)?`...`(?(1)a|b)` -> If group 1 matched, then match a | else match b. Myself I used it rarely yet - usually there is some simpler solutions :)

Comment: @bobblebubble yes something like that, but then I only want to return capture group 2 values if there was no match in group 1 (and I only want to return the first match from either group)

Comment: @JohnHollan I don't get it, maybe you talking about a sequence of multiple rows? Without any sample data and expected output it's difficult. Well, I have some feeling it's interesting, but will surrender for now :)

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. It looks like I can't do what I need with just REGEX, I will have to get under the hood for this customer and write and some code to parse several REGEX expressions to decide which one to use. Thanks!